# How do you set the start/end handles of a curve?

Tags: bezier-curves

I have a curve that isn't a closed loop.

[image]

Is it possible to change the start/end handles so the gap is in a different place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the start and end points of the curve  and press  <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>to make a close loop..

Then delete a segment where you need to open the curve:

[image]